# Javascript text box value and focus order

Tags: javascript, textbox, focus

I have the following Javascript:

```
function PageOnLoadHandler() {
    outputFieldElement = document.getElementById("ConsultantCode"); //

    var position = window.location.href.search("\\?");
    if (position != -1) {
        var querystring = window.location.href.substring(position);
        outputFieldElement.value = querystring;
   }
        outputFieldElement.focus();
}
```

For the following html (cut down):

```
<body onload="PageOnLoadHandler();">
<br/>Enter Consultant Name:

    <input name="ConsultantCode" type="text" id="ConsultantCode" size="30" />
    <br/><center id="ErrorMessage"></center>
</body>
```

It gets the current url string, and attempts to put the querystring section of it into a textbox. My problem is that this only works if I comment out the `outputFieldElement.focus()` line. If this line is present- either before or after setting the value (or both), I can't see the value inside the textbox until I type- then the value appears! Any ideas?

I would like to both have the value, and set the focus to the textbox.

A complication- this isn't on a PC, its on a Mitel IP telephone. So I haven't been able to find out what browser it is using.

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue to me.

Comment: I think the little detail about it being on a phone with some unknown (at least unreported) browser is likely to be pretty important, as (other than the fact that "outputFieldElement" is declared without `var` !!) that code looks fine, and calling "focus()" on an element doesn't cause that sort of problem in "real" browsers.

Comment: Fixed the var issue!
I was just hoping it really wasn't just a browser issue, even though it likely is.

Comment: I tried putting the value of the html text box in code behind- so its embedded in the html instead of in Javascript- it still doesn't display- so really likely its a browser issue! For the record though, if at the end of the above Javascript you set a timer function to set focus in a few milliseconds- then it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
window.onload = PageOnLoadHandler;
```

instead of using `<body onload="....`